# How do I share email contacts across a network without an exchange server?

Tags: linux, email, outlook, exchange-server, linux-mint

I need to have an editable customer contact address book that can be shared over the network and ties into Outlook. I do not have an exchange server but have a server running linux mint. What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

How about Zimbra ? it is a open source  Messaging and Collaboration software. you can share contacts,send emails,IM's etc

You can also use the Zimra connector for Microsoft Outlook.

Here is the reference for that

http://www.zimbra.com/products/desktop-compatiblity.html

there is another open-source project worth to look

http://sourceforge.net/projects/otlkcon/